# I'm trying to make a discord bot command with discord.py that pulls a random quote from a text file and prints it in chat

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Basically, I have a bot that says a random quote whenever I use a command, being pulled from a list. I want to split the quotes list into a separate file then pull a random quote from that file to be used in the command. I've tried lots of different things, including solutions from many other questions on this site, and nothing has worked so far. Here's the most recent iteration of code I tried:

```
    @commands.command(name='fft', help='Responds with a random quote from Final Fantasy Tactics')
    async def fft_command(self, ctx):
        #fft_quotes = ['Names don\'t matter. What\'s important is how you live your life.', 'A \'heretic\' coming to church... pretty bold...', 'Ignorance itself is a crime!']
        mylines = []
        with open('fft_quotes.txt', 'rt') as myfile:
            for myline in myfile:
                mylines.append(myline)
                response = random.choice(mylines)
                emb = discord.Embed(title='FFT Quote',description=response,color=discord.Colour.green())
                await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

The "fft_quotes" line is commented out because I'm trying to use text from the file instead.

Comment: please elaborate on what exactly isn't working, just saying "something doesn't work" isn't helpful

Comment: Apologies. The problem is that *nothing* was working with it, no error messages, no output to Discord or to the CLI, so I really didn't know how to elaborate on it. But I have already found the solution to the problem now. I appreciate all the answers I did receive, and apologize for the poorly worded question.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what the problem was (error or unexpected output), so the best I can do is guess. From the looks of it, it's sending every quote in your quote list, not just a random one.

This would be because you send a random quote inside of the for loop. You should add all the quotes to a list, then *outside* of the for loop send a random quote.

```py
    @commands.command(name='fft', help='Responds with a random quote from Final Fantasy Tactics')
    async def fft_command(self, ctx):
        #fft_quotes = ['Names don\'t matter. What\'s important is how you live your life.', 'A \'heretic\' coming to church... pretty bold...', 'Ignorance itself is a crime!']
        mylines = []
        with open('fft_quotes.txt', 'rt') as myfile:
            for myline in myfile:
                mylines.append(myline)
       # Notice the unindent
       response = random.choice(mylines)
       emb = discord.Embed(title='FFT Quote',description=response,color=discord.Colour.green())
       await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't include any error because the "problem" is that nothing happened. No output, no runtime error, nothing. The bot runs just fine but the command just doesn't *do* anything. I will try the solution you suggested and report back though. Edit: Tried that, nothing happens. I think the issue is that the file isn't being properly imported into Python to begin with, for some reason. But still no output and no errors.

Comment: @Dante do normal commands run? Like, are you able to get any other command to work?

Comment: Yeah, every other command still works, except for that one.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know where is your error but i changed code a bit. Can you try this?

```
@commands.command(name='fft', help='Responds with a random quote from Final Fantasy Tactics')
async def fft_command(self, ctx):
    with open('fft_quotes.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()] #This will read the lines and put them in a list
    emb = discord.Embed(title='FFT Quote', description=random.choice(lines), color=discord.Colour.green())
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this also did not work. It still just doesn't output anything, not even an error message to the client. Maybe I'll try it without the embed and see if that wrks.

Comment: add `print(1)` after `async def fft_command` and check the console after invoking command.